# How to extract str from div section with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get XXXXXXXXXXXXX from this div section with BeautifulSoup.

```
<div class="a-section">
     <form method="post" id="addToCart" action="/gp/product/handle-buy-box/ref=dp_start-bbf_1_glance" class="a-content">
              <input type="hidden" id="ASIN" name="ASIN" value="BOBOBOBOBO">
              <input type="hidden" id="merchantID" name="merchantID" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX">
```

I tried to use this code but it returns None.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

sellingCustomerID= soup.find(id="merchantID")
print(sellingCustomerID)
```

Comment: `sellingCustomerID["value"]` or `sellingCustomerID.attrs['value']` or `sellingCustomerID.get('value')`. Read all documentation for [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to learn all useful functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sellingCustomerID["value"]
sellingCustomerID.attrs['value']
sellingCustomerID.get('value')
```

Read all documentation for [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to learn all useful functions.

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class="a-section">
     <form method="post" id="addToCart" action="/gp/product/handle-buy-box/ref=dp_start-bbf_1_glance" class="a-content">
              <input type="hidden" id="ASIN" name="ASIN" value="BOBOBOBOBO">
              <input type="hidden" id="merchantID" name="merchantID" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX">'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'lxml')
sellingCustomerID= soup.find(id="merchantID")

print( sellingCustomerID["value"] )
print( sellingCustomerID.attrs['value'] ) 
print( sellingCustomerID.get('value') )
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
print( soup.select_one('input[name="merchantID"]')['value'] )
print( soup.find('input', {'name': "merchantID"})['value'] )
```

Comment: Thank you! But how would you try to find the value if you didn't have the `txt`? What code would you write to get that value after scarping a web page?

Comment: I would use `page.content` to get HTML but all depend on page. If page uses JavaScript to add elements then you can't get it with BS/requests and you need Selenium to control web browser which can run JS. Or you have to find url used by JS to get data from server - and then you can use this url. DevTools in Chrome/Firefox can be useful to find url manually.

Comment: I was referring to a certain method which sometimes worked for me but I am not sure how to use it in this case.

This one: `soup.select_one()` but I am not sure what to type after that to only get the value `XXXXXXXXXXXXX` of `name="merchantID"`

Comment: `soup.select_one()["value"] ` or `soup.select_one().attr['value']` or `soup.select_one().get('value')`

Comment: but there are many values on the page. How can I only extract the value that I want that comes after `name="merchantID"`?

Comment: `soup.select_one('input[name="merchantID"])['value']` or `soup.find('input', {'name': "merchantID"})['value']`